# Copy Azure premium storage to standard storage for redundancy

Tags: azure

For our SQL servers we run backups onto a shared premium storage disk. Premium storage is locally redundant and I would like to copy these backups to a standard storage disk in order to take advantage of it's Geo-redundancy. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that I'm aware of would be to just start copying, robocopy is likely the most efficient method.

However, if you are aware writing backups to local disk uses up your alloted IOPS. It is best practice, and recommended by Microsoft, to use the backup to URL for database backups. Doing this does not count against your IOPS for the disk or VM.

Comment: Thanks Shawn, I have actually just started using URL backups.